# Scan QR Code and take picture QR Code at same time?

Tags: android, qr-code

I have a QR code scanner using the ZXing library, now I have to save only the QR code from an image.
I try to take pictures but always on different activities. Like scan activity is not same as taking picture activity. So I have to do 2 times for taking QR code.

1. Scan the QR code
2. Take the picture.
   I want to do that 1 time only and not take to take a picture activity.

I was trying using this `cameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.quickCapture", true);` but it seems like normal taking picture.

I also found an app similar to what I do now.
QR & Barcode Scanner

**From this :**

[image: From this]

**to This :**

[image: to This]

What I want to do is like scan the QR code, crop only the QR Code part, and sending requests to the database.
Or anyways to do that and help, really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

> Scan QR Code and take picture QR Code at same time

If you mean scan qr code and show the qr code as Image then you may follow the answer.

Scan the qr code through `integrator.initiateScan();` then on `onActivityResult` create bitmap of the result through `MultiFormatWriter` and `BarcodeEncoder` and show bitmap in any ImageView and result in any TextView.

```
    MultiFormatWriter multiFormatWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();
            try {
                BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(result.getContents(), BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 200, 200);
                BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();
                Bitmap bitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);
                image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (WriterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Based on your attached Images I am sharing a full activity and a layout file , which will cover your requirements .
This will scan qr code , show result as Image and text also . If the result contains any `url` then it will make it clickable `Linkify` . There are few buttons added to copy result through `ClipboardManager`,share result through Intent .

receive.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linear1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/openButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="Open"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/searchButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="Search"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/copyButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="Copy"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/shareButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="Share"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

    </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/someText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="450dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/someText">

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/image"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="520dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="SCAN AGAIN"
        android:theme="@style/ConnectButton"
        android:id="@+id/scan_btn"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

ReceiveS Activity -

```
public class ReceiveS extends AppCompatActivity {
public static Button scan_btn = null;
ImageView image;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.receive);

    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

    // show custom alert dialog
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.receive);


    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.someText);
    final Activity activity = this;

    scan_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan_btn);
    scan_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
            integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
            integrator.setPrompt("Scan");
            integrator.setCameraId(0);
            integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
            integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
            integrator.initiateScan();
        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.someText);


    final IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (result != null) {
        if (result.getContents() == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You cancelled scanning", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {

            MultiFormatWriter multiFormatWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();
            try {
                BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(result.getContents(), BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 200, 200);
                BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();
                Bitmap bitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);
                image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (WriterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            SpannableString url = SpannableString.valueOf(result.getContents());
            Linkify.addLinks(url, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
            text.setText(url);
            text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());


            Button openlink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.openButton);
            Button webSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
            Button copy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.copyButton);
            Button share = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shareButton);

            openlink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String url = result.getContents();
                    if (url.startsWith("https://") || url.startsWith("http://")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(ReceiveS.this, "Invalid Url", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            });

            webSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String url;
                    url = "http://www.google.com/#q=" + result.getContents();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            copy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                    ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("", result.getContents());
                    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Copied to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
            share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    String shareBody = result.getContents();
                    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share "));

                }
            });


        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
  }
```

Comment: nice, it's been a month I'm stuck at this. hope this will work. Thankss

Comment: So, its create new barcode from result. And it's not cropping picture. My apps need to take a picture not encode new one, my partner create custom qr code with encryption. but thanks for answer